# Is suitable the byzantine generals problem to solve a problem with the report of availability of stroke unit beds?

Tags: game-theory

We are working in a Emergency Medical Service (EMS), wich carries patients in ambulance to the hospital. We are very concerned with the stroke in our community, because we have few beds for many stroke patients. Our problem is:

1. We have 9 hospitals with stroke units.
2. Each hospital has 4 beds in its unit.
3. Each year we have about 2000 stroke code activations, and each patient must be in a stroke unit about 4 days. There are about 2000 stroke patients that not arrive using the EMS.
4. **We should transfer each stroke to a stroke unit with a bed available**, if not there is a system fault and the consecuence is the activation of one aditional ambulance that must transfer the patient between hospitals (to a hospital wich has a free stroke unit bed) with the consequent loss of time.
5. Each hospital must call the EMS coordinator when its unit is full. When it releases a patient (so the unit has free beds), each hospital must call the EMS coordinator as well.

**We have "enough beds" to cover the system**, but we have many "system faults". We are looking for a trustless system with error tolerance, to communicate the beds avalilbility (like cryptocurrency trustless system), because:

1. Maybe there are errors with the communication system (call by phone, unsigned).
2. Negligent staff members of stroke unit may report that the unit is full when it is not actually full.
3. Negligent staff members of stroke unit may also delay the report of the release of unit beds.

I ask this because the problem is similar to the Byzantine generals one ...

Using the role of the game theory, **is there a solution (maybe with signed messages) where we can reduce the possibility of error in the availability of beds in stroke units, using a communication system that maybe has errors because some staff maybe does not behave frankly?**

Comment: You've asked a serious question about a serious problem - but I'm pretty sure there's no mathematical solution, so this is probably the wrong site on which to ask. The problem is requirement (5), which depends on people following rules. I'm sure there are workflow experts who have ideas about how to make that easier, hence more likely. If you're automated and hospital admissions and releases require computer entry, the software could automatically notify your EMS service. @JohnHughes answer is also relevant. Part of your problem is mathematical, and queueing theory may help with that part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The bizantyne generals problem also talks about people following rules. If people knows that using some algorithm that reveals fake messagess about stroke unit bed availability, maybe they will not be motivated to lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer to the question you asked, but instead an answer to a question that I *suspect* that you should have asked:

You've got $8000$ days of bed-use ($2000$ stroke patients times $4$ days).

You've got $13140$ days of beds ($9$ hospitals, $4$ beds each, $365$ days).

If your patient-arrival pattern was **completely uniform**, you'd have about $60\%$ occupancy. If there's even a modest variation, then even if you *always* knew what beds were available, you'd find yourself oversubscribed quite often.

I don't think your problem is an algorithmic one.

Here's the (very simple) simulation code, and some typical output. In this code, I simulate the uniformly random arrival of 4000 patients per year, and simply imagine that there's a single hospital with 36 stroke beds, and that when more than 36 stroke patients are present, they convert beds to stroke-beds.

```
function census_plot()
close all;
years = 4; % 3 year simulation.
days = years * 365;
count = zeros(days, 1); 
patients = 4000 * years; 
beds = 36;

initial = floor(.6 * 36); % start year with 60% occupancy of beds. 
count(1) = initial; % each patient may have been here from 1-4 days already
count(2) = 0.75 * initial;
count(3) = 0.5 * initial;
count(4) = 0.25 * initial;

arrival_dates = randi(days, [patients, 1]);
arrivals = zeros(days, 1);
for i = 1:patients
    arrivals(arrival_dates(i)) = arrivals(arrival_dates(i)) + 1;
end
plot(arrivals);
title('daily arrivals');
disp (['max arrivals: ', num2str(max(arrivals))]);
q = arrivals + [0; arrivals(1:end-1)] +...
    [0;0; arrivals(1:end-2)] + [0;0;0; arrivals(1:end-3)];
% q contains the number of patients (aside from the initial batch) 
% in beds on each day
disp(['max census: ' , num2str(max(q))]);
count = count + q; % and that's the total. 
figure;
plot(1:days, count, 'b', [1, days], [beds, beds], 'r');
title('daily census');
figure(gcf);
disp(['mean census: ', num2str(mean(count))]);
disp(['number of days over max census: ', num2str(sum(count>beds))]);
disp(['fraction of days over max census: ', num2str(sum(count>beds))/days]);
```

And here's the output from a typical run:
Arrivals (in number of patients per day):
[image: Arrivals (in number of patients per day]

Census (i.e., number of beds occupied by stroke-patients. The red line indicates the number of stroke-beds.
[image: Census (i.e., number of beds occupied by stroke-patients. The red line indicates the number of stroke-beds.]

Comment: +1 "Modest variation" with $50\%$ utilization might be OK. The departure pattern is variable too. The OP might have enough data to get an approximate queueing theory estimate for the probability of oversubscription.

Comment: Agreed. I just did a simulation in matlab for 4 years with a completely uniform arrival distribution. It shows 3 or 4 days, on an average run, where they need more beds than they have, and about 50 days (over the 4 years) in which at least 30 beds are full, at which time you're shuffling people to relatively distant hospitals. I suspect (although this is sociology, not math) that the right way to get staff to report available beds is probably to incentivize it, not to use weird algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. My problem is not about beds availability, it is about notifying you correctly and "in time". I forgot an important fact: there are an aditional ~2000 patients that doesn't arrive by ambulance (I added it). Using the role of the game theory, is there a solution (maybe with signed messages) where we can reduce the possibility of error in the availability of beds in stroke units, using a communication system that maybe has errors because some staff maybe does not behave frankly? People my act honestly if they know the algorithm will identify the bad actors.

Comment: This sounds as if you have an answer in mind, and are looking to contort the question until the answer is appropriate. If you add 2000 patients, and the typical stay is 4 days, then in a year, you have 12000 patient-days, and about 13000 bed-days. In my simulation, which *assumes* that each patient is allocated to an empty bed if there is one (or a new bed is temporarily made a stroke-bed), it turns out that in a typical run, for **fully $98$ percent** of the days in a 4-year period you're over census. Something's definitely wrong with your model or reporting of the situation.

Comment: Excuse me: with the additional 2000 patients, you've got 16000 patient days and 13000 bed days. If you still think that the problem is empty-bed reporting, then...we must be understanding the facts very differently. Game theory cannot make a smaller number be larger than a larger number.

Comment: Thanks J Hughes. The system is obviously overload, and there are  some patients that cannot access to an ictus unit bed.